# SQL-SERVER why my cascading delete gets stuck

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB with about 100 tables. One table `Client` is referenced by almost all other tables (directly or indirectly).

I am trying to delete all data of one `Client` by executing this query:

```
DELETE FROM Client 
WHERE Id = SomeNumber
```

this query should `CASCADE` delete all rows in all the tables that are

connected, directly or indirectly, to this `Id` of `Client`

**The problem is that the query is getting stuck and I don't understand why.**

this is the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkChYasYu)

I checked for locks by this script

```
 select * from sysprocesses where blocked > 0
```

but no result. didn't get any errors also. and I don't have any triggers in my DB.

I do see that a couple hundred of rows from some table are been deleted but

after a few seconds the query get stuck.

Comment: install sp_whoisactive and try to execute it when your query stucks

Comment: thanks I will try, is there another way that I can check it ?

Comment: you can run builtin  sp_who  , but sp_whoisactive give you more information at one run

Comment: Side note, you should really stop using those old compatibility views and use the new ones; they're designed for old SQL Server 2000 databases. See [Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu got it

Comment: @eshirvana I run sp_whoisactive in status column  it say `suspended`  do you know why ?

Comment: what was the wait ? was it showing any blocking pid?

Comment: `wait_info` was `(4ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:TestCliniClicks3:1(*)`

Comment: PAGEIOLATCH_SH wait latency up to 10ms is normal . but if its taking more than that you should be investigating. is there any blocking process either blocking your process or something else?

Comment: ..a few indexes might be missing…start with the “big” tables.. Log(clientid), WebApplicationEvent(clientid), TreatmentDraft(patientid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can quite clearly see in the plan, that some of the dependent tables do not have indexes in the foreign key.**

When a cascade happens, the plan starts by dumping all rows into an in-memory table. You can see this with a `Table Spool` at the top left of the plan, feeding off the `Clustered Delete`.

Then it reads these rows back, and joins them to the dependent tables. These tables *must* have an index with the foreign key being the leading key, otherwise you will get a full table scan.

**This has happened in your case with a large number of tables,** in some cases double-cascaded with two scans and a hash join.

When you create indexes, don't just make a one-column index. Create sensible indexes with other columns and `INCLUDE` columns, just make sure the foreign key is the leading column.

---

I must say, with this many foreign-keys, you are always going to have some issues, and you may want to turn off `CASCADE` because of that.

Comment: so do you think its better to use SP instead ?

Comment: No, why would that make a difference, you need to think about indexing these foreign keys

Comment: Because I thought that if I will turn off CASCADE and manually delete all records from all tables that are connected to Client  it will not get stuck, am I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry I thought you just meant putting it into a stored procedure, as opposed to ad-hoc batch, which makes no difference. It will be mostly the same issue: it will take a long time because of poor indexing. Although you would be able to split it up into sections, so it may not be quite as bad, also the query plans will be simpler, which may speed up compile times. But I think you should index first, before you consider anything else

Comment: I added some indexes this is the new query plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkhW6pZcO
 - but it still getting stuck -

Comment: That's not really any different. You still have a lot of Index Scans on the secondary tables. Some of them even have primary keys which are not clustered. You need to have *every one* of those tables indexed on its foreign key

Comment: can you give me an example, what do you mean by secondary tables ?

Comment: and another thing adding so many indexes will not make the `insert` command slow ?  
isn't a bad practice to add many indexes to a rare operation of deleting a client ?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding more indexes to the `Client` table you are deleting from. It is the child tables such as `InvoiceTreatment` (the ones which reference this one, and have cascading deletes) that you need to look at. Yes, extra indexes will slow down inserts and updates, but you are only adding one index per table, so each table will only be affected by that one index. At the same time, inserts and deletes on `Client` will be massively sped up

Comment: By the way, if you can get your database to Compatibility Level 140, it may speed up compile times a lot also, this is because of the new Foreign Key Check query plan operator

Comment: yes I understood that I need to add `indexes` to the child tables but I wanted to make sure that I need only to add index to `ClientId` `FK` in the child tables, I will add them up

Comment: What do you think maybe adding the `ClientId` to the `PK` clustered index of the child tables will be a better approach ?  or it's not significate ?

Comment: You can do that, it's often a good option especially for many-to-many join tables. But it *must* be the leading key column, it's useless for this purpose otherwise